# Sections that compilation ignores (Texmaker)

Tags: sectioning, texmaker, windows

Can I create "sections" in a .tex document that compilation will ignore, but will be reflected in the structure of the document, as displayed in texmaker to the left of the window?

When I write a .tex document with Texmaker (windows) and I use the commands `\section` or `\subsection`, this is reflected on the left side of the window: there is a list of all sections, subsection, subsubsections etc... This list is extremely useful for navigation within a document. Can I have a list like this show up while using texmaker, that will be ignored by the compiling process?

I need it for easy browsing and better orientation within the document.

My solution at the moment is very primitive: I use the standard `\section` command, and once I'm done writing the text, I place `%` signs in front of the sections I want Latex to ignore.

**Edit** I've noticed today that sometimes texmaker still displays `%\section{whatever}` as a real section in the sidebar, but I'm not sure wether it's a bug or a feature, and I don't know what triggered it, nor what turned it off eventually.

Comment: According to the [Texmaker documentation](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION14), you can add up to three bookmarks to each document.

Comment: @ChrisS This is a viable option. It's a shame you can't put more though.

Comment: In version 3.2.2 -> 3.3 : [commented structure entries are no more used in the structure view](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html), may be based on [majority votes at issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=470&can=1&q=commented%20sections&colspec=ID%20Type%20Summary) it may be included. In TeXmaker, `Edit`--> `Refresh Structure` to get the updated the Structure

Comment: @texenthusiast I see, that's a shame, I could really use that feature.

Comment: You can 'cheat' a little by adding the `comment` package, and saying `\begin{comment}\section{I'm not here}\end{comment}`, though that is a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be several ways …

### 1 use the bookmark feature (by texenthusiast)

TeXmaker provides the option to add up to three book marks to your code. (TeXstudio which is a more flexile fork, can add up to ten book marks)

### 2 use the `comment package` (by Torbjørn)

```
\usepackage{comment}
% ...
\begin{comment}
   \section{I'm not here}
\end{comment}
```

### 3 hide it from TeX with booleans

You can use `\iffalse` which is a boolean operation that is always false and the following code will be ignored. Every `\if…` must be ended with a `\fi`.

```
\iffalse
   \section{I'm not here}
\fi
```

### 4 using different files

This is not a real answer to you question but maybe it will help if you separate your code in several files and load them with `\input` or `\include`. I guess `\input` would be better here (see [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/4918)). Again I like the handling of multiple files in TeXstudio better.

Comment: The `comment package` is just what I needed, thanks!